# How can I delete a password and lock the account in one step?

Tags: passwords, linux

I have a minimal server install on a remote machine with a root password set to a temporary, but chosen, value.

I have added a separate administrator user. This user has an authorized key for SSH, no password access, and passwordless sudo.

I would like to remove any trace of the root password and lock the root user.

This can be done with `passwd -d root && passwd -l root`. However, this leaves a window between the two operations for bad behavior. How can you take both actions in one step?

This is more of an academic question than a practical one. My solution is `sed -e -i -e 's/^root:\([^:]*\)\(.*\)$/root:!!\2/' /etc/shadow`, but it feels like there should be a less error-prone, idempotent operation.

Comment: I indeed find a bit strange that `passwd` interprets the `-d` flag applied on a locked account as "*delete the password* ***and unlock the account***". The only documented behavior of this flag is to remove the passwords, not unlock the accounts...

Comment: From the passwd manpages on a debian flavored machine
>-l, --lock
>           Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>           password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
>           encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).
>
>           Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be
>           able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).
>           To disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>
So the way you lock an account is to make its password hash have a !.

Comment: Its logcal that deleting the password than also unlocks the account, it also deletes the lock after all.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the root password?  What value does that provide above locking the account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try:

`usermod -p '!!' root`

`usermod` with the `-p` parameters takes the raw value to bet set as encrypted password in the `/etc/shadow` files.

The traditional usage of this parameter is to give to `usermod` an already encrypted password, but it accepts also the `'!!'` flagging the account as locked.

In the end, this command will remove the current password and leave only the exclamation marks setting the root account as locked in the `passwd` way¹, all in one move using a safe and standard command, thus fulfilling the request.

---

¹: According [to this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109314/two-ways-to-lock-a-password-but-only-one-to-unlock), there is no established standard on the way to lock an account. So `usermod -L` uses only a single exclamation mark (`!`) in front of the hashed password to lock it, while `passwd -l` uses two (`!!`).

Answer (score 1):

To delete and lock an account with passwd(1) in one command, simply specify both `-d` and `-l` in the same invocation:

`passwd -dl root`

Comment: As embarrassingly obvious as this answer was, I nonetheless must credit [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/104140/245043) for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: This does not work with `passwd 0.79`, in use on RHEL 7 systems. I do not know what minimum version of `passwd` is required for this functionality.